# multiple xhr.get s with dojo

Tags: ajax, dojo

how do I do two xhr.gets one after the other using dojo ?

I have ....

```
require(["dojo/_base/xhr", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!"],
function(xhr, dom) {

    // Using xhr.get, as very little information is being sent
    xhr.get({
        // The URL of the request
        url: "inc/etl2json.php?item=Execs",
        // The success callback with result from server
        load: function(execContent) {
            dom.byId("Execs").innerHTML = execContent;
        },
        // The error handler
        error: function() {
            // Do nothing -- keep old content there
        }
    });

});
```

I would like to do another xhr.get to *"inc/etl2json.php?item=Execs"* and assign it to *dom.byId("Elapsed").innerHTML = elapsedContent;*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just call again xhr.get() inside the load function, well that if the content is supposed to change, else you could just use the same data retrieved the first time:

```
xhr.get({
    load:function(data){
        //use the first data you retrieved
        xhr.get({
            load: function(data2){
             //do what you like with the nuew data
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Although nesting is a straightforward solution it almost always leads to unreadable code, so I would do the same as @Ricardo did, but use the advantage of Dojo's [Deferred](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.7/dojo/Deferred) (+ [here](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/_base/Deferred)) and employ chaining:

```
var requestUrl = "inc/etl2json.php?item=Execs";

xhr.get({ url: requestUrl})
    .then(function(results) {
        dom.byId("execs").innerHTML = results;
    })
    .then(function(results) {
        return xhr.get({ url: requestUrl});   
    })
    .then(function(results) {
        dom.byId("elapsed").innerHTML = results;
    })
```

See it in action at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/73X88/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add another `xhr` call for the *elapsedContent*. I don't see any relation between the two calls so you should make them separate. Nesting one in another is not necessary.
just add

```
xhr.get({
        // The URL of the request
        url: "inc/etl2json.php?item=Execs",
        // The success callback with result from server
        load: function(elapsedContent) {
            dom.byId("Elapsed").innerHTML = elapsedContent;
        },
        // The error handler
        error: function() {
            // Do nothing -- keep old content there
        }
    });
```